# Convert "10.1.1.1-10.1.1.3" format to "10.1.1.1-3"

Tags: text-processing, awk, cut

I know this is possible, probably by using `awk`, but I can't think the solution for now.

How do I convert IP format from

```
10.1.1.1-10.1.1.3
10.100.100.11-10.100.100.31
```

to

```
10.1.1.1-3
10.100.100.11-31
```

Here is my attempt with `cut`, but didn't really work as expected.

```
wolf@linux:~$ echo 10.1.1.1-10.1.1.3 | cut -d . -f 1,2,3,4
10.1.1.1-10
wolf@linux:~$ 

wolf@linux:~$ echo 10.100.100.11-10.100.100.31 | cut -d . -f 1,2,3,4
10.100.100.11-10
wolf@linux:~$
```

Comment: You could have asked the original question... you might have got a better answer than my attempt with brace expansion: https://www.reddit.com/r/bash/comments/jer6ip/how_to_expand_ip_address_in_dash_format/

Answer (score 6):

Here’s a generic solution using AWK, adapting to the number of common components:

```c
BEGIN {
    FS = "-"
}

NF == 2 {
    split($1, start, /\./)
    split($2, end, /\./)
    printf $1
    for (i = 1; i <= length(start); i++) {
        if (start[i] != end[i]) {
            for (j = i; j <= length(end); j++)
                printf "%s%s", (j > i ? "." : "-"), end[j]
            print ""
            next
        }
    }
    print ""
}
```

This will also handle cases like `1.2.3.4-1.2.5.6`, printing the correct range:

```
1.2.3.4-5.6
```

Answer (score 4):

Here's a `sed` approach. It will look for everything up to the last `-` on the line, save that as `\1`, then save the last occurrence of a `.` followed by one or more digits as `\2`. The entire line is then replaced by `\1\2`:

```
$ sed -E 's/(.*-).*\.([0-9]+)/\1\2/' file 
10.1.1.1-3
10.100.100.11-31
```

Alternatively, in `awk`, you could set the input field separator to `.` or `-`, and the output field separator to `.`, and then print the frist through fourth fields, a `-` and the last field:

```
$ awk -F'[-.]' -vOFS="." '{print $1,$2,$3,$4"-"$NF}' file 
10.1.1.1-3
10.100.100.11-31
```

Answer (score 4):

An option with `awk`:

```
awk -F'[.-]' '{ print $1"."$2"."$3"."$4"-"$8 }'
```

Output:

```
10.1.1.1-3
10.100.100.11-31
```

Answer (score 1):

```
LC_ALL=C sed 's/^\([0-9.]*\.\)\([0-9]\{1,\}-\)\1\([0-9]\{1,\}\)$/\1\2\3/'
```

Would give the expected output for lines that are in the `anything.digits-anything.digits` and leave the lines that don't match that pattern (like `1.2.3.4-1.2.6.254`) alone.

Answer (score 1):

```
$ sed 's/-.*\./-/' file
10.1.1.1-3
10.100.100.11-31
```